# Measuring time needed to run empty ReactJS function produces strange result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, time

I am optimizing execution time of react application. I am using console.time() to measure time spent to run certain function. The function below does absolutely nothing.

```
onClickCompany = (e) => {
   e.stopPropagation();
   e.preventDefault();

   console.time('myTimer')
   console.timeEnd('myTimer')
}
```

Function call:

```
<div title={company}
  key={id} 
  onClick={this.onClickCompany}>
  { company } 
</div>
```

In browser console such function takes 0.007ms but within React app it takes: 
[image]

Does anyone know why does it happen? Why does it take so long to run empty function?
appreciate any help!

Comment: I'm able to replicate this. Not to quite the extent that you are though. I get result of around 0.008ms running this in my console, but through React's onClick handler that goes up to around 0.120ms ([CodePen](https://codepen.io/inb4/pen/KWoJQO)). I haven't a clue why this is happening though, mind you.

Comment: Do you get the same result by listening to the `onMouseDown` event instead? Maybe it's related to some kind of browser-specific click debounce.

Comment: guys, thank you for replies! i managed to cut time by half by reducing the depth of nesting. Apparently, that was part of a problem. Still investigating...